# a,b are positive integers. If $21ab^2$ and $15ab$ are perfect squares, the minimum values of a+b is?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I tried by splitting $21ab^2$ and $15ab$ and equating them to distinct integers $m^2$ and $n^2$.

$2100 + 10a + b^2 = m^2$

$1500 + 10a + b = n^2$

Subtracting,

$900 + b^2 - b = (m + n)(m-n)$

After that I am not able to proceed further...

For reference the answer of the question is $56$.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: $21ab^2$ is product of $21$, $a$ and $b^2$. Why you think they're digits of a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $21ab^2$ and $15ab$ are perfect squares, then so is their product

$$ 21\cdot 15\cdot a^2b^3 = 3^2\cdot a^2b^2\cdot5\cdot7\cdot b$$

For $5\cdot7\cdot b$ to be perfect square, min $b=5\cdot7=35$.

Also $15ab = 3\cdot5\cdot a\cdot5\cdot7$ is a perfect square $\Rightarrow $ min $a=3\cdot7=21$

Check that for these values $21ab^2 = 21^2b^2$ is indeed a perfect square.

Comment: Thanks a lot cosmo5 !. My mistake  I read it the wrong way ;)